# Creating a cube with custom back end on Ocean for petrel, what SeismicCubeGeometry should we define?

Tags: c#, ocean, petrel

I am creating a cube using

```
SeismicCube c = SeismicSystem.ExternalBulk3DService
    .CreateSeismicCube(seismicCollection, externalBulk3D)
```

And the geometry of the cube is:

```
SeismicCubeGeometry(size,
    new Point3(100, 100, 100),
    new Vector3(1, 0, 0), new Vector3(0, 1, 0),
    new Vector3(0, 0, -0.2), Domain.ELEVATION_DEPTH)
```

I am not sure how to calculate the 3 vectors. Create cube throws an exception saying the cube lattice is different from the survey lattice. Where can I find and use the survey lattice? How are the vectors calculated?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: I have tried: 
{(existingCube.SampleSpacingIJK.X, 0 , 0), (0, existingCube.SampleSpacingIJK.Y, 0), (0, 0, -existingCube.SampleSpacingIJK.Z)}

  and    {(existingCube.SampleSpacingIJK.X * cos(existingCube.SpatialLattice.OriginalLattice.Single.RotationI), 0 , 0), (0, existingCube.SampleSpacingIJK.Y * cos(existingCube.SpatialLattice.OriginalLattice.Single.RotationJ), 0), (0, 0, -existingCube.SampleSpacingIJK.Z)}   and     {(1,0,0), (0,1,0),(0,0,1)}.       
I get System.InvalidOperationException with the info {"The lattice does not match the survey lattice."}